# Javascript works in JSfiddle but not browser

Tags: javascript, html

Im having troubles with adding javascript to my html code. The code works in JSfiddle but not in my html code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<link href="dropdownmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body>


<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : '593528484105939',
        xfbml : true,
        version : 'v2.2'
    });
};
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.se";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

so this is one of the javascript codes and it doesn't work even if i change the opening tag to 
`<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Do you see any errors or anything in your console?

Comment: You didn't close your `<head>`.

Comment: silly question: why are you using XHTML in a modern HTML5 world? (if the answer is for more rigid syntax, the irony should not be lost on us here)

Comment: 2014/10/28 - [W3C Declares HTML5 Standard Complete](http://techcrunch.com/2014/10/28/w3c-declares-html5-standard-done/).

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You are missing closing head and body tags, so if this is treated as XML, nothing at all should work. While the type attribute was required in HTML 4, it has not been necessary in practice for a very long time (more than a decade), and even then only in a very specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Close your `Head` Tag and try again, if it is still not working they try to use

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

you can use both or one of the above link by replacing it on

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link href="dropdownmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId : '593528484105939',
                xfbml : true,
                version : 'v2.2'
            });
        };
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.se";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</body>
```